# How to query single document which contains specific value of some element in array of arrays MongoDB

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have an document that contains array of arrays i am using embedded document in MongoDb.Say i have collection name Orders looks like:-

```
"_id" : "HjPGrdkffg7dQPtiX",
    "ListOrdersResult" : [
        {
            "Orders" : {
                "Order" : [
                    {
                        "LatestShipDate" : "2016-01-13T18:29:59Z",
                        "OrderType" : "StandardOrder",
                        "PurchaseDate" : "2016-01-11T10:24:49Z",
                        "PaymentExecutionDetail" : {
                            "PaymentExecutionDetailItem" : {
                                "PaymentMethod" : "COD",
                                "Payment" : {
                                    "CurrencyCode" : "INR",
                                    "Amount" : "839.30"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "BuyerEmail" : "vccdbptpx2ssd74882@marketplace.amazon.in",
                        "AmazonOrderId" : "402-4031538-7451469",
                        "LastUpdateDate" : "2016-01-14T06:47:17Z",
                        "ShipServiceLevel" : "IN Exp Dom 2",
                        "NumberOfItemsShipped" : "1",
                        "OrderStatus" : "Shipped",
                        "SalesChannel" : "Amazon.in",
                        "ShippedByAmazonTFM" : "false",
                        "LatestDeliveryDate" : "2016-01-19T18:29:59Z",
                        "NumberOfItemsUnshipped" : "0",
                        "BuyerName" : "xyz",
                        "EarliestDeliveryDate" : "2016-01-13T18:30:00Z",
                        "OrderTotal" : {
                            "CurrencyCode" : "INR",
                            "Amount" : "839.30"
                        },
                        "IsPremiumOrder" : "false",
                        "EarliestShipDate" : "2016-01-11T18:30:00Z",
                        "MarketplaceId" : "A21TJRRWUN4KGVC",
                        "FulfillmentChannel" : "MFN",
                        "TFMShipmentStatus" : "Delivered",
                        "PaymentMethod" : "COD",
                        "ShippingAddress" : {
                            "StateOrRegion" : "HARYANA",
                            "City" : "GURGAON",
                            "Phone" : "9999999999",
                            "CountryCode" : "IN",
                            "PostalCode" : "122001",
                            "Name" : "Murthy",
                            "AddressLine1" : "House No. , J Block, Badshahpur"
                        },
                        "IsPrime" : "false",
                        "ShipmentServiceLevelCategory" : "Expedited"
                    },
                    {
                        "LatestShipDate" : "2016-01-13T18:29:59Z",
                        "OrderType" : "StandardOrder",
                        "PurchaseDate" : "2016-01-11T13:16:49Z",
                        "PaymentExecutionDetail" : {
                            "PaymentExecutionDetailItem" : {
                                "PaymentMethod" : "COD",
                                "Payment" : {
                                    "CurrencyCode" : "INR",
                                    "Amount" : "899.40"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "BuyerEmail" : "xyz@marketplace.amazon.in",
                        "AmazonOrderId" : "402-2142159-5087541",
                        "LastUpdateDate" : "2016-01-14T06:47:15Z",
                        "ShipServiceLevel" : "IN Exp Dom 2",
                        "NumberOfItemsShipped" : "1",
                        "OrderStatus" : "Cancel",
                        "SalesChannel" : "Amazon.in",
                        "ShippedByAmazonTFM" : "false",
                        "LatestDeliveryDate" : "2016-01-19T18:29:59Z",
                        "NumberOfItemsUnshipped" : "0",
                        "BuyerName" : "demo prakash",
                        "EarliestDeliveryDate" : "2016-01-13T18:30:00Z",
                        "OrderTotal" : {
                            "CurrencyCode" : "INR",
                            "Amount" : "899.40"
                        },
                        "IsPremiumOrder" : "false",
                        "EarliestShipDate" : "2016-01-11T18:30:00Z",
                        "MarketplaceId" : "A21TJEUUN4WGV",
                        "FulfillmentChannel" : "MFN",
                        "TFMShipmentStatus" : "Delivered",
                        "PaymentMethod" : "COD",
                        "ShippingAddress" : {
                            "StateOrRegion" : "DELHI",
                            "City" : "DELHI",
                            "Phone" : "99999999",
                            "CountryCode" : "IN",
                            "PostalCode" : "110038",
                            "Name" : "Demo prakash",
                            "AddressLine1" : "Hn 638 gali n 04 Wazirabad new delhi"
                        },
                        "IsPrime" : "false",
                        "ShipmentServiceLevelCategory" : "Expedited"
                    },
                    }
                ]
            },
            "CreatedBefore" : "2015-03-19T06:17:59Z"
        }
    ],
    "ResponseMetadata" : {
        "RequestId" : "cf94645e-ada7-4ec6-b161-a97d07a77817"
    },
    "seller_user_id" : "yg4e34ccodzf3GPR2",
}
```

So as you can see this is the single document that contains the whole data of array i want to fetch the orders whose status is cancel from this order array.

So for that i have use :-

> var orderDetails =
>   orders.find({"ListOrdersResult.Orders.Order":{$elemMatch:
>   { OrderStatus:"Canceled"}}}).fetch();

Also i tried with:-

> orders.find({"ListOrdersResult.Orders.Order.OrderStatus":'Canceled'}).fetch();

So this will return the whole document that contains status as canceled and other as well but i want only selected result from the document that contains status as pending.

So is there any way in mongoDb to query a selected value from a single document that contains nested array of arrays as object.

Or I need to staore the values into diff diff documents thats only the solution.

Any help would be appriciated please contribute

Thanks!

Comment: Try using aggregate of mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with any meteor aggregate package. You can use match and then group the data then send it to client-side.Like :

```
var ordersLines = orders.aggregate([
                      {$unwind : "$ListOrdersResult.Orders.Order"},
                      {$match : { OrderStatus:"Canceled"} },
                      {$project : {
                      OrderType : '$ListOrdersResult.Orders.Order.OrderType'
                      ....  
                           }
                      }
                  ]);
return ordersLines;
```

But I suggest you go with a different document.